# Use different Color for different ActionBar.Tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to have all tabs in ActionBar to have different Color Indicators, for example blue for tab 1, red for tab 2 etc.

To achieve that I did create different selectors for all colors and put them in different xmls in drawable. In style.xml I am calling them by

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyleRed</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTabStyleRed">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_red</item>
</style>
```

I've created that style for different colors too. Now when I change the drawable or style to different color, it works. I can see colors being applied to tabs. But since all tabs are of same color, it didn't solve my purpose. I tried to set style of tabs in `onTabSelected()` but there's no method to do that.

Ultimately I tried to create different themes for different colors and tried to set them programtically in `onTabSelected()`, but then I got to know that theme must be set before `setContentView()`.
So My questions is..How can I do that? Is there any way I can have different colors for different tab indicators???

**Update:-**
the drawable/tab_indicator_red.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_red" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_red" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_red" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_red" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_red" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_red" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_red" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I'vo got one, but I have to clear some things out-> In the selector, what do you have in the place of the "..." ? Do you use different styles for the different colors? How do you use the styles. If all the tabs have to be different colors, how do you set them separately (or that's the question here) ?

Comment: @g00dy updated the question with more details. And you got it right, that's the question here. I am open to all the ways which can result in different color indicators for different tabs, either through xml,selectors, or by java code. I'd prefer the way which is least troublesome. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I have a starting point for you but it is a little bit fiddly.
Setting up the action bar with the following code you can set the tabs to use you custom look:

```
  //...somewhere in oncreate
  ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    TextView tv1 = createTab("Tab 1", R.drawable.firsttabdrawable);
    tab1.setCustomView(tv1);
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
    tab2.setCustomView(createTab("Tab 2", R.drawable.secondTabDrawable));
    tab2.setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = bar.newTab();
    tab3.setCustomView(createTab("Tab 3", R.drawable.thirdTabDrawable));
    tab3.setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = bar.newTab();
    tab4.setCustomView(createTab("Tab 4", R.drawable.fourthTabDrawable));
    tab4.setTabListener(this);  

    bar.addTab(tab1);
    bar.addTab(tab2);
    bar.addTab(tab3);
    bar.addTab(tab4);
```

createTab method as follows:

```
  private TextView createTab(String titleText, int tabBackgroundDrawableId)
{
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //set caption and caption appearance
    tv.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyDefaultTabTextAppearance);
    tv.setText(titleText);
    //set appearance of tab
    tv.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundDrawableId);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //Make sure all tabs have the same height
    tv.setMaxLines(2);
    tv.setMinLines(2);

    return tv;      
}
```

However the actionbar seems to add the tab view to a parent view that adds padding so for each one you need to remove it.  I did this in the oncreate after the first code block like so:

```
  View view = (View) tv1.getParent();       
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You may find a more graceful/straightforward way of doing this but as a starting point I thought it was worth posting.

Hope this helps.

ADDED:

It may also be worth pointing out that if you have a more complicated layout for your tab you can inflate a layout xml file in the createTab method instead. For example using the following xml (mytab.xml):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabIcon"/>
<TextView style="@style/MyDefaultTabTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tabIcon"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:id="@+id/tabText"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

createTab becomes:

```
  private RelativeLayout createTab(String titleText, int tabBackgroundDrawableId)
{
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mytab, null, false);  
     //set appearance of tab
    rl.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundDrawableId);

    TextView tv = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
    //set caption       
    tv.setText(titleText);     

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon);

    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);//or supply unique drawable to method?      
    return rl;      
}
```

Comment: That's pretty good solution. I was thinking that using custom view is the only solution here. Instead of using textview, I am using a RelativeLayout as custom view. The problem is even after setting the parent padding 0, the icon which I am setting in RelativeLayout is not in center and in landscape mode the tabs get screwed. Let me know if you have any fix for that too. ALthough the problem is almost solved, since I can set background of relative layouts, but it kinds of overlays on existing indicator. So probably I'll need to hide the existing indicator too.

Comment: PS: My tabs just have icons and indicators, no textview in them

Comment: @Creator I have added a little more to my answer that may help you use a relativelayout as your tab.  I have tested my example shifting from portrait to landscape and cannot see any issue with the tabs layout but if you can elaborate further I can try to help. If your tab background is not completely covering the entire square space available to your tab I would suggest adding an outer layout (linear/relative) whose background is a solid color e.g. black.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've already implemented a solution based on your answer, forgot to mark it as accepted. Sorry for that. Thanks again for the addition. Cheers!!!